# Обращение к стороннему jar

Tags: java, gradle

Приложение sprig boot.
Собираю gradle.
Хост - linux

/-root
|
|_home/lib/ExternalLib.jar
|
|_var/lib/app.jar

В проекте нужно использовать сторонний ExternalLib.jar, который лежит на хосте в отдельной папке.
Этот ExternalLib.jar загружен в nexus.
Загружен только для того чтобы собрать приложение.
Для сборки приложения использую compileOnly('ExternalLib').
Приложение собирается - все ок.

При выполнении - получаю java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, что очевидно.

Вопрос как правильно обращаться к ExternalLib.jar который лежит на хосте?

Comment: Я запускаю приложение через ключ -jar  %JAVAHOME%/bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar /var/lib/app.jar Ключ -cp никак.